# Excel VBA: Grouping months in Pivot Table without getting error?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write macros that create two pivot tables from separate sheets back to back, and group them by month but every time I try to run my code I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
    Sub PivotTable()
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("Information").UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R1C4", TableName:="PivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
With Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("PN")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
End With
         With Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Commit")
 .Orientation = xlColumnField
 .Position = 1
         End With
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum", xlSum
End Sub

     Sub GroupPivot()
   Dim therange As Range
   Dim PT As PivotTable
   Set PT = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable")
   Set therange = PT.PivotFields("Commit").DataRange.Cells(1)
   therange.Select
   Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
False, True, False, False)
End Sub

Sub PivotTableNY()
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("InformationNextYear").UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="PivotNextYear!R1C4", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
With Sheets("PivotNextYear").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Material")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
End With
  With Sheets("PivotNextYear").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Deliv. Date")
 .Orientation = xlColumnField
 .Position = 1
 End With

Sheets("PivotNextYear").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Sheets("PivotNextYear").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Open Quantity"), "Sum", xlSum
End Sub

Sub GroupPivotNY()
Dim myrange As Range
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = Sheets("PivotNextYear").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set myrange = PT.PivotFields("Material").DataRange.Cells(1)
myrange.Select
Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
False, True, False, False)
End Sub
```

I keep getting this error message:

> "Rum time Error '1004': Select Method of Range class failed."

The error appears in line: `therange.Select` under Sub GroupPivot.

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Comment: also just write `theRange.Group ...` if you try to select a range and a different sheet is active then what you expect it will fail.

Comment: @dwirony what two numbers do I put in there? That happens to be some code I found online and I don't understand that bit too well. My pivot table starts D1, and the dates I want to group start on E2

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I got rid of the select and it gave me the error: Cannot group that selection. `Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
False, True, False, False)
End Sub` was where I got that error. Is this because of what the other comment was saying? I need to put 2 numbers in criteria?

Comment: @ctallofamer It depends on what you're trying to do, which I cannot tell... Could you try and clean up this bit of code? it's 6 subroutines with 0 formatting, it's an eyesore to try and navigate.

Comment: see @K Paul answer below. I think it has more to do with that then @dwirony's point.

Comment: @dwirony sorry, I cleaned it up a bit. I am just trying to group the dates for  the two pivot tables I made. The pivot table starts on column 4 row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Worksheets("Pivot").Activate
```

before

```
therange.Select
```

Comment: I added that and I am getting error: Run time 1004: Cannot group this selection.

Comment: What's the purpose of Cells(1)? Without being able to test it myself, I'd try removing .Cells(1) so it reads: Set therange = PT.PivotFields("Commit").DataRange

Comment: @cthallofamer Any luck?

Comment: So I didn't get any errors, but the dates did not group, instead, the first column of the pivot table grouped.

Comment: Okay, let's back this up. Put .Cells(1) back in. It's necessary for the grouping function I think. Then go back through your data and make sure you don't have any blanks in the date column that you're trying to group. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Make sure that your Pivot Table Range doesn't have any blank rows either.

Comment: Okay, so after putting .Cells(1) back in the first pivot table grouping works. For the second pivot table I am having trouble though. It doesn't have any blanks for the entire date row, the column with the material #s also doesn't have any blanks, however some of the data within the pivot table is blank.. (just as it was in the first pivot table.)

Comment: What error is it giving you for the 2nd pivot table? Did you use the correct sheet name in the Worksheets("").Activate statement?

Comment: Everything is spelled properly, I made sure of that a couple times. It just keeps saying: Runtime error 1004: Cannot group that selection.

Comment: when I manually try to group it it works fine, I just need it to be a macro, I'm looking online but cant seem to find a solution